# Update panel implementation?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, caching, updatepanel

I was looking around the web for some information about, how the update panel is implemented in asp.net ?

Was looking for how the caching of the update panel script which is served through axd and the query string generation for it.

Yeah, I can go through the scripts but I think it will definitely not written keeping me in mind and also it does not gives the entire picture.

Will appreciate if somebody can post and/or point to some explanation.

Thanks, Biswanath.

Answer (score 2):

This link does a pretty good job of it:

[UpdatePanel Control Overview](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)

Comment: Nice link. Is there some resource around, which talks about the script javascript generation part ?